# adb usb interface e00002c5 is already in use, and adb server didn't ack

Tags: android, macos, adb

Every time I use adb in my terminal it always get errors as follows:

`daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
adb E 07-25 11:33:33 52658 1792500 usb_osx.cpp:333] Could not open interface: e00002c5
adb E 07-25 11:33:33 52658 1792500 usb_osx.cpp:294] Could not find device interface
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *`

I am sure there is no other program using 5037:

[image: port info]

As the log says, there must be some software using the usb interface right now.
But how can I find It?

Meanwhile, I do not have Gennymotion simulator on my laptop.

Comment: Try this sommand
    adb kill-server
    adb start-server

Comment: I have tried this and other method on stackoverflow. But they do not work.